# PHP Gmail API Get Label Name Not Id

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API & PHP to get a batch of messages via the API. All works fine, but when I am looping through my results it is giving me the Label IDS and not the label names. I find that it would be REALLY inefficient to have to loop over each message to swap the label ids with the label names before outputting the data. How can I JUST get the label names and not the IDS in the in API request.

Here is my code:

```
$batch = new \Google_Http_Batch($client);

// loop over ids to add
foreach($list as $message_data){
    $message_id = $message_data->getId();
    $optParams = ['format' => 'full'];
    $message = $service->users_messages->get("me", $message_id, $optParams);
    $batch->add($message, $message_id);
}
```

When I loop over my results and I print the labels I get something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => IMPORTANT
[1] => STARRED
[2] => CATEGORY_PERSONAL
[3] => Label_1231231231
[4] => INBOX
)
```

This label id Label_1231231231 seems pretty pointless. **I just want the label name, not the id.**

Thanks.

Comment: At users.messages.get, the label IDs are returned. So how about using [users.labels.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get)? In this method, the label names can be retrieved from the label IDs using ``$labels = $service->users_labels->get("me", $labelid)``. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated, but that would make it so that I cannot get the full message details just labels.

Comment: If I misunderstand about your situation, I'm sorry. I had thought that the message and label ID are retrieved using users.messages.get, and as an another method, it retrieves the label name from the label ID using users.labels.get. Unfortunately, because both the label name and full message cannot be directly retrieved by one method.